# How to use logcat

Tags: android, eclipse

How do I use logcat in Eclipse? I know where it is, but it is always blank and nothing shows up in it. What could the problem be?

Comment: How are you running your app? In the simulator, or on a connected Android device?

Comment: I am running my app on a connect android device and I am very new to Eclipse so it is probably just a user error.

Comment: and how did u confirmed that ur devices is connected with adb?

Comment: @Ankit Can he run the app if it isn't?

Comment: Yes the debugging is on and is connected with the adb.

Comment: @Keyser u always can install app on device, there is no need of connection with ADB for it.

Comment: @Ankit But isn't it hard to accidentally do that?

Comment: Check that you don't have any filters activated. You want to show all messages.

Comment: @Keyser Agree, but beginners do these kinda things. I can tell u many example of these types. but this is not a platform to discuss this thing :)

Comment: @Keyser see which answer he accepted!!

Comment: Sorry Guys, You were awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you try to print something on the logcat like.

```
 Log.d("tagname","string you want to execute");
```

in your code?

then check on the logcat environment in the left side, if you have selected a filter, to be safe choose "All message(no filter)" button.

Comment: There was a filter that was disrupting it, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your left panel where you will found symbol of device, click on it, and select your appropriate device or emulator, hope it will provide you info into your logcat.

[image]

If you are still not getting anything then `restart` your adb